# jquery data table losing data from second page

Tags: asp.net, datatables

I am using the [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) library for pagination with my [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)project. When i am trying to save data, it saving data only for current page and losing data for all other pages. The table is placed inside a repeater.

What can I do to fix this? Please suggest a solution.

**ASPX HTML part:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
          <th>Period</th>
          <th>Period Date</th>
          <th>Account</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="gradeX">
      <td style="display: none;">
        <asp:Literal ID="litID" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Literal ID="litPeriod" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Literal ID="litPeriodDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Literal ID="litAccount" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" CssClass="form-control btn-rounded" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Server side code C#:**

```
private void SaveTableData(string BudgetID) {
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  foreach(RepeaterItem row in rptData.Items) {
    Literal litID = (Literal) row.FindControl("litID");
    Literal litPeriod = (Literal) row.FindControl("litPeriod");
    Literal litPeriodDate = (Literal) row.FindControl("litPeriodDate");
    Literal litAccount = (Literal) row.FindControl("litAccount");
    TextBox txtAmount = (TextBox) row.FindControl("txtAmount");

    DOL.Budget objBudget = new DOL.Budget();
    objBudget.ID = Convert.ToInt32(litID.Text);
    objBudget.BudgetID = BudgetID;
    objBudget.AccountNumber = litAccount.Text;
    objBudget.Period = litPeriod.Text;
    objBudget.PeriodDate = DateTime.ParseExact(litPeriodDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
    objBudget.Amount = Resources.Helper.ValToDecimal(txtAmount.Text);

    BAL.Budget.Insert_Details(objBudget);
  }
}
```

Comment: Show ur SQL, I guess you are updating every row.. and since the data is not visible on LISTVIEW.. IT will not get any values for it

Comment: If i remove pagination it save all the data. But when i use pagination it loses all the data except the current page. In SQL its just an insert statement